# Linux on iMX6 and CMA memory

Tags: linux, memory, virtual-memory

We have a embedded linux system(yocto 1.8) running on a i.MX6 board with 1GByte of RAM. The kernel is configured to have 320MByte of CMA reserved and no swap. Kernel 3.10.53

When we run a small test application just to eat up memory we see a strange behavior when we reach about 250MByte free, the buffers/caches starts to decrease and the free memory stays at around 250MByte. If we keep allocating memory the system becomes more and more sluggish until it completely grinds to a halt or the OOM killer kicks in.

I think what i'm wondering is how the CMA actually works, because of we disable the CMA, we see the same behavior as above, but it happens when we have around 40-50MBytes free, and i believe that is expected.
After reading about CMA i believe the pool should not be withheld completely from the system, it should still be viable for caches etc, but
in our case it appears that the system discards the caches while there is plenty of memory left.

Does anyone know if this is the expected behavior, or if there is a better place to put this question?

Edit:
It appears we had changed the value of vm.min_free_kbytes to 32MBytes.
Changing back to the default value does seem to allow us to use all memory.

We're still not sure how the CMA is actually affecting the system, but that may not be as important any more.

Comment: Not sure how CMA works, but ordinary malloc() uses *optimistic memory allocation*.  See http://www.linuxdevcenter.com/pub/a/linux/2006/11/30/linux-out-of-memory.html